# counting occurrence of specific word in csv using pycharm

Tags: python, csv

I have three columns in csv file, and I want to go through "title" column and count the number of occurrence of specific word, so I started with the coding but i get an error. The code is:

```
import csv
import collections

Title = collections.Counter()
with open('Green Occupations.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
        Title[row[1]] += 1

print 'Number of word "..": %s' % Tiltle['wind']
print Title.most_common()
```

and i get this error:

```
Title[row[1]] += 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

An example of the data I have

```
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  SOC Code  |              Title              |  Occupational Category  |
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 11-1011.03 | Chief Sustainability Officers   | New & Emerging          |
| 11-1021.00 | General and Operations Managers | Enhanced Skills         |
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Any idea ? :)

Comment: An example of your csv file please

Comment: You might want to check the length of the row before accessing it. `if len(row) < 2: continue`.

Comment: Example of title raw: Wind Energy Project Managers
But the first column has code #, and the the third one has text like: New green

Comment: Please *copy and paste* some of your *complete* csv file by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44099280/edit) your post. If it contains sensitive data, replace them with similar text. We don't like guessing.

Answer (score 0):

try the following piece of code

```
def get_count(title):
    count=0
    title=title.lower()
    f=open('Green Occupations.csv')
    l3=[[s.strip() for s in lines.split(',')] for lines in f.readlines()]
    l4=[item[x] for item in l3]
    for item in l4:
        if item.split(' ')[0].strip('"').lower()==title:
            count+=1
    return count
print(get_count('Industrial'))
```

## assumig titles in column x and above list comprehension gives list of titles

and if your titles in 3rd column replace x by 3.

```
occurence=get_count(title=)
# will return no of occurence starting with title
```

Comment: I didn't get where should i add this ? I tried it and i still get an error which says : TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Error 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable arises because i missed parenthesis on f.readlines method whic i have edited now.

Comment: I'm sorry, still didn't get the X part. what do you mean by this and where exactly should i put the 3.  I'm a beginner at this and trying to learn by myself

Comment: titles=[item.strip().split(',')[x] for item in f.readlines()], here it is , already replaced by 0 according to your data. always start count from 0 and 3rd column has value x=2. if you are beginner don,t jump to sea until you know how to swim. follow tutorials as many as you can just to stand in pythons world and start learning from python books eg from o'reilly.com where you can find good materials.

Comment: Yes i understand, but my adviser asked me to do this for my project. I did this and the result is 0 i don't understand why

Comment: did you replace 'title' by your required search title in line occurence=titles.count('title'). it works correctly here on my data. you can email me your csv data and your desire i will you provide proper solution.

Comment: This would be great ! thank you so much for offering this. Can i have your email, I'll send you the data and the codes i tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pandas?
It would make the job very easy:

```
import pandas as pd

#Import data from csv
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, delimiter=';')

search_word = 'Officer'  #example

# Check if each title contains the specified word and then count
counts = df['Title'].str.contains(search_word).sum()
```